# Select one div at a time on dynamic divs

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to select one box at a time and have it display a popup when hovered, but they have the same div classname and every time i hover, all the other boxes pop up as well.

```
<div class="parent"> //select one at a time when hovered here
<a href="#" class="show">show content1</a>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<a href="#" class="show">show content2</a>
</div>

<div class="hidden">show this text one at a time when hovered</div>
```

I tried to use .on jquery because it's not binded to a single element, and .toggle, but it doesn't work and it displays all at the same time.

http://jsfiddle.net/2XG9j/9/

Comment: I dont understand your requirements. what do you mean one at a time? or all at the same time. at first I thought it was a message, but since its the same message, I dont get what you need

Comment: each hidden mesage will be different as they will be created dynamically, but in the example, i just made it a static message

Comment: Check my answer. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Would a tooltip satisfy your requirements? https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/p9rwop58/

```
<div class="parent"> 
<a href="#" title="show1 this text one at a time when hovered">show content1</a>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<a href="#" title="show2 this text one at a time when hovered">show content2</a>
</div>

<div style="display: none;">show this text one at a time when hovered</div>

$(".parent").tooltip();
```

Comment: i want to add a lot of information so i don't really want to use this

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the event for each element:

```
$('.show').each(function(i,e){
    $(e).click(function(){
        $('.hidden').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly. try this

http://jsfiddle.net/anbby8se/

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(e){
        $('.hidden').text($(e.target).text());
        $(".hidden").css({
                'display' : 'block'
            });

    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(".hidden").css({
                'display' : 'none'
            });
    }
}, '.parent');
```

Note that Im just grabbing the content of the anchor. because I don't know what you want to show.